# Satis with local git repository trouble

Tags: php, composer-php, satis

I've read [this](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) for setting up a local Satis server, I've managed to do it and see the web view on my virtual host. Now, I have two projects listed there, one requires the other. On another project I require the one that depends on the other, then run php composer install and it says:

> Problem 1
>
> ```
> - Installation request for my/project dev-master -> satisfiable by my/project dev-master.
> - my/project dev-master requires my/otherproject dev-master -> no matching package found.
> ```

From the link before, and many others I've read, they have something like this:

> { "type": "vcs", "url": "http://github.com/mycompany/privaterepo" }

which is fine, but my projects have a /home/me/some/path/to/repo and im not sure if this is why I  can't get it to work?

Edit:

Ok, I found [this](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md)

> Package not found#
>
> Double-check you don't have typos in your composer.json or repository branches and tag names.
>
> Be sure to set the right minimum-stability. To get started or be sure this is no issue, set minimum-stability to "dev".
>
> **Packages not coming from Packagist should always be defined in the root package (the package depending on all vendors).**
>
> Use the same vendor and package name throughout all branches and tags of your repository, especially when maintaining a third party fork and using replace.

But isn't Satis a local Packagist? So this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to your problem is `Be sure to set the right minimum-stability. To get started or be sure this is no issue, set minimum-stability to "dev".` Since my/project requires my/otherproject dev-master, your root package must allow my/otherproject to be installed in dev versions.

Either you set `"minmum-stability":"dev"`, which will allow all packages to be installed in dev, or you can add a require like `"my/otherproject":"@dev"` which just allows this one to be dev, but not others.

Obviously a better solution to this is to start tagging releases. That way my/project can require 1.* or something of my/otherproject, and you won't have problems anymore.